# Как правильно показать холдер с размерами картинки в Picasso?

Tags: android, recyclerview, picasso

Использую список `RecyclerView`. В айтеме есть фото. Оно грузится через `Picasso`. Во время загрузки я сделал чтобы плэйсхолдер был просто серым прямоугольником. Но его высота гораздо больше высоты картинки. Высота фото приходит от сервера. Поигрался с ней, но ничего не получается, при быстрой прокрутке вообще ужас происходит. Если прокрутить и подождать остановки, то плэйсхолдеры заменяются фотографией по очереди и список дергается. К примеру, в приложении ВК, на стене, плэйсхолдерам ставится высота как у фото.

Разметка айтема

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textColorLink="@color/link_text"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/photoView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="#B8B8B8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<View
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Адаптер

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
{
static final int POST = 0;
static final int LOAD_MORE = 1;

boolean isLoading;
int itemHeight;
List<Post> list;
AdapterListener listener;
Context ctx;
int layoutID;
Picasso picasso;
ColorDrawable drawable;

public class PostHolder 
extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener
{
    ImageView photoView;
    TextView postText;

    PostHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        photoView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoView);
        postText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void bind(int position)
    {
        Post post = list.get(position);
        int w = post.getWidth();
        int h = post.getHeight();
        final String text = post.getText();
        if (text.length() < 250)
        {
            postText.setText(text);
        }
        else
        {
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text.substring(0, 250) + " Подробнее");
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View textView)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder full = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                    full.setMessage(text);
                    full.create().show();
                }
                @Override
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
                {
                    super.updateDrawState(ds);
                    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
                }
            };
            ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, ss.length() -  9, ss.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            postText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            postText.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            postText.setText(ss);
        }
        final String url = post.getUrl();

        picasso
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(drawable)
            .resize(0,h)
            .into(photoView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();

        return true;
    }

}

public class LoadMoreHolder 
extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
implements OnClickListener
{
    Button load;
    ProgressBar pb;

    LoadMoreHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        load = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.load_more);
        pb = (ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadmore_pb);
        load.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void bind()
    {
        load.setVisibility(isLoading ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        isLoading = true;
        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listener.loadMore();
    }
}

PostAdapter(List<Post> list, Context ctx, AdapterListener listener, int layoutID)
{
    this.layoutID = layoutID;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.list = list;
    this.picasso = Picasso.with(ctx);
    drawable = new ColorDrawable();
    drawable.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
}

void setOnAdapterListener(AdapterListener listener)
{
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
{
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int itemType)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    if (itemType == POST)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(layoutID, parent, false);
        return new PostHolder(v);
    }
    else
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loadmore, parent, false);
        return new LoadMoreHolder(v);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    if (getItemViewType(position) == POST)
    {
        ((PostHolder)holder).bind(position);
    }
    else
    {
        ((LoadMoreHolder)holder).bind();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if (position == getPostCount())
    {
        return LOAD_MORE;
    }
    return POST;
}


public int getPostCount()
{
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    int postCount = getPostCount();
    if (postCount == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return getPostCount() + 1;
}

void loadingEnd()
{
    isLoading = false;
}

public interface AdapterListener
{
    void loadMore();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Вашей разметке у `ImageView`, если нет объективной причины принудительно растягивать изображение по ширине, необходимо поправить размеры:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ...
/>
```

Что касается отрывка:

```
...
picasso
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(drawable)
        .resize(0,h)
        .into(photoView);
...
```

а конкретно:

```
.resize(0,h)
```

никогда не пытался и не уверен, что оно меняет размер placeholder-a, но точно знаю, что оно меняет размер загружаемого изображения.

В данном случае, я порекомендовал бы в placeholder передавать `Drawable` нужного размера, например так:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthPx, heightPx, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY)
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context, bitmap);
```

Если размеры всех изображений одинаковое, то такую инициализацию drawable лучше делать единожды и вынести в отдельный метод.

Если изображения часто совпадают по размерам, то лучше сделать кэш с drawable для placeHolder-ов, а Canvas лучше сделать final static полем класса, иначе в большом списке вы столкнётся с такой проблемой, как сборщик мусора, который будет заметен в виде зависаний при скролинге.

Если все изображения всегда разные и их очень-очень много, то вам лучше задуматься об одном экземпляре усреднённого по размерам drawable для placeholdera.

Comment: Так и знал что нужно копать в сторону `Drawable` для плэйсхолдера. Сейчас попробую :)